# Need SQL Shorthand - PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Ok My eyes hurt :) Anyone suggest a much shorter way to accomplish the same code?

Valid values for the following variables could be:
$ryg could be: "all", "r", "y" or "g"
$region could be: "all", "na", "emea", "latam" or "apac"

I need to shorten/optimize this but my eyes hurt after a long day coding (no wonder)

```
if(($region=="all")&&($ryg=="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0));
} else if(($region=="all")&&($ryg!="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND data1_summary.overall_ryg=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,$ryg));
} else if(($region=="na")&&($ryg=="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,"na"));
} else if(($region=="na")&&($ryg!="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? AND data1_summary.overall_ryg=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,"na",$ryg));
} else if(($region=="emea")&&($ryg=="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,"emea"));
} else if(($region=="emea")&&($ryg!="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? AND data1_summary.overall_ryg=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,"emea",$ryg));
} else if(($region=="latam")&&($ryg=="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,"latam"));
} else if(($region=="latam")&&($ryg!="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? AND data1_summary.overall_ryg=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,"latam",$ryg));
} else if(($region=="apac")&&($ryg=="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,"apac"));
} else if(($region=="apac")&&($ryg!="all")) {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? AND data1_summary.overall_ryg=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,"apac",$ryg));
} else {
  $sql_main= "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
  $stmt->execute(array('y',0,$region));
}
```

I got tired just cutting and pasting all of that ...

Thoughts on the shortest way to re-write this ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This isn't programming. This is chaos. You **really** need to read up on loops. [Like right now.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) When you see repetition, that's a sign you need to collapse this into some kind of loop structure. Make an `array` of the possible values and iterate over it.

Comment: :) thanks. i'm with ya.

Comment: The strategy here is to figure out what parts change and what parts are fixed, then make some kind of look-up table that defines what modifications to make based on particular region/ryg pairs.

Comment: thanks tadman. these are the thoughts I'm looking for and ill go figure it out. appreciate the feedback.

Comment: When you do get it, I'd encourage you to post a self-answer if someone else hasn't pitched in. It'll help demonstrate how to turn this monstrosity into something simple and maintainable. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to reduce code:

```
if ($region == "all" && $ryg == "all") {
    $sql_main = "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
    $stmt->execute(array('y', 0));
} elseif ($region != "all" && $ryg != "all") {
    $sql_main = "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? AND data1_summary.overall_ryg=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
    $stmt->execute(array('y', 0, $region, $ryg));
} elseif ($region != "all" && $ryg == "all") {
    $sql_main = "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND project.region=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
    $stmt->execute(array('y', 0, $region));
} elseif ($region == "all" && $ryg != "all") {
    $sql_main = "SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project WHERE project.active=? AND project.account_key=? AND data1_summary.overall_ryg=? ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
    $stmt->execute(array('y', 0, $ryg));
}
```

Although you can still optimize this, you dont have to add conditions for every region or ryg anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had just gotten this far but works perfectly. I'll continue working on making this as short and maintainable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_main = "SELECT * FROM project 
    INNER JOIN data1_summary ON project.p_key = data1_summary.p_key_project 
    WHERE project.active = ? AND project.account_key = ? "
    .(($region != "all" ? "AND project.region = ? " : null) ?: 
    ($ryg != "all" ? "AND data1_summary.overall_ryg = ? " : null)).
    " ORDER BY data1_summary.projected_margin ASC";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_main);
$stmt->execute(array('y',
    (($region != "all" ? "0,$region" : 0) ? 
        ($ryg != "all" ? "0,$ryg" : 0) : 
        (($region && $ryg) != "all") ? "0,$region,$ryg" : 0)
));
```

Not tested, but this should work also.